# Terminal Command Output to array in CPP

Tags: c++, pthreads, wkhtmltopdf

I have a folder and subfolder which contain many HTML files. I want to store all the html file paths to an array. I am using C++ and ubuntu.
I know a terminal command - `find . -name *.html` which gives me all the html file paths.
 I want to use these paths to create PDF of these HTML files using `WKHTMLTOPDF` and threading. How to store these paths and use it?

Comment: I wouldn't use an external command to get the list of paths to your html paths but rather stick with c++. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c)

Answer (score 0):

You could brute-force it by using `std::system`

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

to execute your find command and use the output in a C++ program. Or read up on file system traversal in Steven's APUE ('Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment) and do it yourself. Begin with `man 3 stat`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But what if i have lakhs of html files. It will store first on text file and then reading text file would not be a good solution i think.